# Tableau - Plotting multiple lines in one graph

Tags: plot, tableau-api

I'm trying to plotting multiple lines in one single graph. I've combined two of them using dual axis, but I don't know how should I add another.

Thank you in advance for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that you want to show multiple measures in one viz it means that one axis is sufficient for all these measures.  Therefore, Instead of creating dual axis chart, do it like this-

**Step-1** Build line chart with one measure.

**Step-2** Drop another measure on the axis directly instead of rows/column shelf where you'll see a double bar icon like the screenshot.

[image]

**step-3** Drop additional mesaures either in similar ways or onto measure values pane created automatically.  See a demonstration screenshot below on sample superstore

[image]